# NPM Build issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Trying to run this command: npm run build.
Here is the scripts definition of the package.json file
"scripts": {
"start": "npm run build",
"build": "webpack -d, --devtool && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
"build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
},
"keys": [
"reactjs"
],

This is the error been produced regardless I also tried for build in scripts webpack -d, wepack -d --devtool as well webpack -d, --devtool nothing helped. The error shows as

[webpack-cli] Error: Option '-d, --devtool ' argument missing
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /Users/naveed.hasan/Projects/demo/react/fileuplod
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot

Comment: The webpack.config.js file attached here.                                                                var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
module.exports = { devtool: 'source-map'};
var config = {"entry": SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js", "output": {"path": DIST_DIR + "/app","filename": "bundle.js","publicPath": "/app/"},"module": {loaders: [{test: /\.js?/,include:SRC_DIR,loader: "babel-loader",query: {"preset": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]}}]};

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma after your -d in your script:

`"build": "webpack -d, --devtool`

-----------------------------^ there

I'm not a webpack user, but it doesn't look voluntary

Comment: I tried both webpack -d --devtool nothing worked. Can someone please guide what the correct format should be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should configure the [devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) option, either in the command line `-d eval` or in your `webpack.config.js` file :

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    devtool: 'eval',
    ...
};
```

Comment: I added what  you suggested into webpack.config.js but no luck. I an providing snippet from both here...module.exports = {
    //devtool: 'source-map'
    devtool: 'eval',
};      The package.json :   "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d, --devtool && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  }, The Error: [webpack-cli] Error: Option '-d, --devtool <value>' argument missing

Comment: I added the package.json & webpack.config.js into public git. Can you please look into it and help resolve the issue. https://github.com/biteus/react_demo/tree/stackoverflow

Comment: instead of `webpack -d devtool`, can you try `webpack -d eval`, otherwise you can just write `webpack && && cp src/app/index.html ...`

Comment: No luck..Olivier, I already shared the source into a public git hub. Can you try in   your system and push a branch that works in your system. This issue is really giving me run around. I am expecting something simple but because I am to this, having hard time figure out. Thanks

Comment: BTW, can you please review my "webpack.config.js" in case issue lies there. github.com/biteus/react_demo/tree/stackoverflow

Comment: I clone your repository, there are multiple errors (not only devtool). The loader is not correctly configured, the babel-core dependency is missing. I think you should use react-create-app (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to initialize your application, your project will be automatically configured.